# How to set custom JSP project url to default url on using tomcat8 local server?

Tags: tomcat8

I setup Tomcat8 and upload jsp project in webapps directory.
Now I can visit my site with the url like "http://sitename/project name/web".
But I hope my project to show when visit "http://sitename".
I tried to find solution but nothing is helpful.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the directory named `ROOT` in `webapps` directory and put into your jsp file and rename to `index.jsp`.

If you create `ROOT` directory or `ROOT.war` in `webapps` directory, then the application can be accessed without `/[context-name]`, like "http://sitename/your.jsp".

In addition, Tomcat regards index.jsp as the welcome file by the following default settings in `conf/web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So you can access to `ROOT/index.jsp` by requesting to "http://sitename".